# "Машина девушки" and "машина у девушки" - what's the difference?

Tags: грамматика, родительный-падеж

I understand that the possessor is in the genitive case but what is the difference between `машина девушки` and `машина у девушки` and `у девушки есть машина` and `я вожу машину девушки` and `я вожу машину у девушки`?

Comment: "машина девушки" is unambiguous phrase, genitive case and sign of possessions. But "машина у девушки" have 2 meaning really - it could too mean physical location only. "я вожу машину у девушки" - f.e, he drives just around/near the girl. :> 
"я вожу машину у березы". "я вожу машину у девятиэтажки". "я таскаю тачку у ямы". "я сейчас вожу коляску у той вон девушки"

Answer (score 4):

I would assume that "девушка" in these sentences stands for someone's girlfriend though it could be some other girl.

`машина девушки` is most simple – "my girlfriend's car"

`машина у девушки` is usually used as a part of a sentence. Like "а что за машина у девушки?" — "What kind of car does your girlfriend have?" Or "моя машина сейчас у девушки" — "My car is currently at my girlfriend's place"/"I gave my car to my girlfriend for now"

`у девушки есть машина` – "my girlfriend has a car"

`я вожу машину девушки` - "I drive the my girlfriend's car"

`я вожу машину у девушки` – This doesn't sound naturally. I'd translate it as "I drive a car at my girlfriend's place" or something like that.

Comment: The preposition "у" can be possessive or locative, so "машина у девушки" can mean both "girlfriend has a car" and "car at girlfriend's place".

Comment: Yep. That's what the second example for the sentence is about

Answer (score 1):

The combinations of words "машина" and "девушка" in numbers 1 to 4 express approximately the same meaning -- "car [which] belongs to girl [and I drive it]". Number 5, however, might sooner mean  "I drive the car [in the company/firm/organisation] belonging to the girl". It would hardly relate to the girl's possession of the car itself.